# Meteor.methods and security

Tags: security, methods, meteor

say I have a Meteor.method `addCredits(user, amount)`, that add the specified amount of credits to the user account. Then what is stopping a potential hacker from just scanning the source code, find the method, and call it from the client console?

Comment: See also [Preventing collection modifications via console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915575/how-to-prevent-collection-modification-via-console-for-an-otherwise-secure-updat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is stopping a hacker from doing that. In the method, you must check that the user has done something that gives him the right to call the method.

Answer (score 2):

Making sure users only execute methods they are allowed to is done by checking `this.userId` within the method on the server.  That id gets set when the user logs in and is available in all methods.  If no user is logged in `this.userId` equals `null` inside a method.

Management of user account and associating the userId with a connection is handled by using the accounts system, such as using the packages 'accounts-base' and 'accounts-password'.  The accounts system is documented [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_api).

`this.userId` is documented [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#method_userId).

An example of how to restrict method execution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21763616/728291).

Comment: This answer the question "How do I know if a user is signed in a method?", not the question asked.