# How to prevent collection modification via console for an otherwise secure update operation?

Tags: meteor

I am fairly new to Meteor and am just trying to figure out meteor security.

I am writing a quiz app that allows a logged in user to save their scores. I have created a collection which consists of a user id and an array of scores. The way I expose a push of new score is a method on the server side:

```
Meteor.methods({ 
  'pushScore' : function(playerId, playerScore) {
    UserScores.upsert({ userId : playerId}, {$push : {scores : playerScore}});
  }
});
```

I call the method on click of a button from the client like so:

```
if (Meteor.userId()){
  Meteor.call('pushScore', Meteor.userId(), Session.get("score"));
}
```

I have the following concerns here:

- Obviously the user can manipulate the score value in "Session" and cheat the system. What could be an alternate secure mechanism to keep track of the running score while a quiz is being taken?
- The other one is probably a bigger concern. How do I prevent the user from just firing a console call to my method "pushScore" and again cheat the system by adding, say a score of 100?
- Is there an inherent flaw in the way I have designed here?

This is just a sample application, but I can easily imagine a real world scenario which could mimic this. What woudl be a best practice in such a scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers..

Answer (score 4):

As @Peppe suggested, you should move the logic to the server somehow. The main rule for Meteor security (and web security in general) is

## You cannot trust the client.

The reason for that is what you've already mentioned: if there is something a client can do, then there is no way to stop a rogue user to do the same thing from the browser console, or even to write his own malicious client that will exploit the leak.

In your case, that means that if client is able to add points to scores, then the user is able to do so as well, regardless on what security measures you employ. You can make this more or less difficult, but your system has a designed leak which cannot be completely closed.

Thus, the only bulletproof solution is to make the server decide on when to assign points. I assume that in a quiz app user gets points when he choose the right answer to a question. So instead of checking that on the client, create a server–side method that will receive the question ID, answer ID, and increase user scores if the answer is correct. Then make sure user cannot just call this method with all possible answer, with a way that corresponds to your quiz design – for example give negative points if wrong answer is chosen, or allow to answer the same question only once in a period of time.

Finally, make sure the client doesn't just get the correct answer ID in the data it receives.

Comment: Thanks. That explanation makes sense. Let me re-engineer my quiz app keeping these points in mind and I'll try and post my refactored code here.

Comment: I disagree, why send data to the server so it can send data to the mongo when the client can interact with his own mongo client and let mongodbs oplog to take of the rest?
I believe in strong "Meteor.allow" validation and trust the client completely, I believe interacting with the data through mongo is the "Meteor Way"

Comment: @ErezHochman: we're saying the same thing. Validation in `Meteor.allow` means that the server runs the logic to decide whether an update can be made or not, which is my point. I didn't say that you shouldn't insert/update on the client and rely on methods only. It's just that in this particular case you need an information that is not included in the update (you update only the score value, but need information on the question and answer).

Comment: Thus in this particular case, I think it's simpler to create a method so that this additional information can be easily transferred. If in your architecture you could access all the information necessary to make the decision – for example if you wanted to include the question id along with the score event – then it would be simpler to update on the client and validate in allow. Still, the server would make the decision, and in this meaning the client wouldn't be "trusted".

Comment: Oh,now I understand, and yes, I agree that if you need to enrich your data using methods is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, there are 2 common soloutions to your problem:

1. if you're using a Meteor.method dont pass any arguments in the Meteor.call, the server can and should gather the data it plans to insert/update on the server side.
2. you can add a validation function to the collection using the collection "allow" method to verify any updates from the client, in that case you don't need the Meteor.method and can just update from the client and validate it server-side.

Comment: and make sure you remove the "insecure" package.

Comment: I think I understand the suggested methods. But I don't see these solving my specific scenario. May be I am missing something. In my case, this is an authenticated user. So they have the right to add a new quiz score. As I am not keeping track of the completion of a quiz in a collection, can I validate against a client side action on the server update code to mark the completion of a quiz? For eg. can I check if the submit quiz button was clicked on the UI before I allow a new score push on the server side update method?

Answer (score 2):

Security (insert/update/delete operations) in meteor works in the same way as security in any other framework: before executing an action taken by the user, make sure the user has the rights to perform it. Security may appear as a weakness in Meteor, but it does not suffer from it any more than other frameworks (though, it's easier to exploit it in Meteor through the console).

The best way to solve it probably varies from case to case, but here's an example: if a user posts a post, the user should gain 5 points. Here's a bad way to solve it:

```js
if(Meteor.isClient){

    // Insert the post and increase points.
    Posts.insert({userId: Meteor.userId(), post: "The post."})
    Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {$inc: {'profile.points': 5}})

}

if(Meteor.isServer){

    Posts.allow({
        insert: function(userId, doc){

            check(doc, {
                _id: String,
                userId: String,
                post: String
            })

            // You must be yourself.
            if(doc.userId != userId){
                return false
            }

            return true

        }
    })

    Meteor.users.allow({
        update: function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier){

            check(modifier, {
                $inc: {
                    'profile.points': Number
                }
            })

            if(modifier.$inc['profile.points'] != 5){
                return false
            }

            return true

        }
    })

}
```

What makes it bad? The user can increase his points without posting a post. Here's a better solution:

```js
if(Meteor.isClient){

    // Insert the post and increase points.
    Method.call('postAndIncrease', {userId: Meteor.userId(), post: "The post."})

}

if(Meteor.isServer){

    Meteor.methods({
        postAndIncrease: function(post){

            check(post, {
                userId: String,
                post: String
            })

            // You must be yourself.
            if(post.userId != this.userId){
                return false
            }

            Posts.insert(post)
            Meteor.users.update(this.userId, {$inc: {'profile.points': 5}})

        }
    })

}
```

Better, but still bad. Why? Because of the latency (the post is created on the server, not the client). Here's a better solution:

```js
if(Meteor.isClient){

    // Insert the post and increase points.
    Posts.insert({userId: Meteor.userId(), post: "The post."})

}

if(Meteor.isServer){

    Posts.allow({
        insert: function(userId, doc){

            check(doc, {
                _id: String,
                userId: String,
                post: String
            })

            // You must be yourself.
            if(doc.userId != userId){
                return false
            }

            return true

        }
    })

    Posts.find().observe({
        added: function(post){

            // When new posts are added, the user gain the points.
            Meteor.users.update(post.userId, {$inc: {'profile.points': 5}})

        }
    })

}
```

The only disadvantage this solution suffers from is the latency of the increment of the points, but it is something we must live with (at least at the moment). Using observe on the server may also be a disadvantage, but I think you can get pass it by using the package collection hooks instead.

Comment: I think the second way (using Meteor.methods) is probably the simplest, if the post creating latency is such a problem you can consider adding a stub for your meteor.method and handle the UX so the user won't feel it.

Comment: In fact, in real life the third way often turn out to be simpler. Plain collection operations are a bit easier to maintain in the long run. To make the code more clear, instead of an observer you can use the [`matb33:collection-hooks`](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks) package to write an after-insert hook.

Comment: Thanks @Peppe! I will try and incorporate some of your suggestions in my refactor

Comment: How about [a Meteor.method that does the same thing for both the server and the client](https://www.meteor.com/try/10)? On the client, it will act as a stub.

Comment: @DanDascalescu, yea, that should work (as Erez mentioned), but then you need to validate the post both in the method and in allow/deny rules. This validation can of course be factored out into a separate function so you don't need to duplicate your code, but it makes your code more complex. Guess it's up to you how you want it to work.